# Update UI controls outside the updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm trying to update controls outisde the update panel with the ref. of below link . but its not working. i want to know what i'm missing.in my application can't use these labels inside the update panel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301423(v=vs.110).aspx

```
HTML

 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Updatepaneltest._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(PageLoadingHandler);
    function PageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {
        var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
        if ($get('Label1') !== null)
            $get('Label1').innerHTML = dataItems['Label1'];
        if ($get('Label2') !== null)
            $get('Label2').innerHTML = dataItems['Label2'];
    }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
   UpdatePanel content.
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<hr />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="hiii" runat="server" /> <br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // ScriptManager ScriptManager1 = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label1, DateTime.Now.ToString());
            ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label2, DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Control updates inside of updatepanel,**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="hiii" runat="server" /> <br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Control updates outside of updatepanel,**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="hiii" runat="server" /> <br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
```

Later, write below lines in client side.

```
var pageInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
pageInstance.add_pageLoaded(UpdateLabelHandler);

function UpdateLabelHandler(sender, args)
{
  var ControldataItems = args.get_dataItems();
  if ($get('Label1') !== null)
    $get('Label1').innerHTML = ControldataItems ['Label1'];
  if ($get('Label2') !== null)
    $get('Label2').innerHTML = ControldataItems ['Label2'];
}
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label1, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label2, DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: sorry in my case i can't use these labels inside the updatepanel.is there any other option..?

Comment: It seems, my answer too mentioning the same.

Comment: sorry i didn't find ur updated answer. its working fine.

Comment: Hi..can u check with textbox. its not working in textbox .but its working in label.